# Preload tableview data before selection

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, tableview, preload

I have a tab bar app with 5 tab bar items. My tab bar "item 1" has a tableview that populates from a server based property list.

Now, by default the app launches with tab bar "item 0", but when I select my tab bar for the tableview ("item 1") it takes a few seconds to populate whilst the data is retrieved from the server.

Is there a way I can preload the required data for the tableview when the app is launched, that way there would be no delay when the tab bar tableview ("item 1") is selected?

PS: I know I can change the default tab bar item to "item 1" in the app delegate and this does solve the problem because the splash screen displays until the tableview is populated, but I really want tab bar "item 0" as the default.

Answer (score 1):

You can begin an asynchronous download of data in the app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method and later use the results in the table view's data source.